# Plotting variable axis ticks

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

Hi trying to make variable y(or x) axis ticks based on calculating the min and max. Here is what I tried so far:

```
ymin = (round((min(ECG_Data)), 1))
ymax = (round((max(ECG_Data)), 1))
..
plt.ylim(ymin - 0.05, ymax + 0.05)
plt.yticks(np.arange(ymin - 0.1, ymax + 0.2, step = 0.1))
```

**Example 1**

[image]

lowest value is about -0.38 with lowest tick -0.4, which is great. But highest value is above 0.9 and the tick stops at 0.9, which I don't want.

**Example 2:**

[image]

Perfect example but as you can see in the code above, I used hard coded - and + values in ylim & yticks which only works for this particular graph.

(If I don't use numeric values into plt.yticks, both lower & upper ticks are missing, like example 1 where highest tick is missing)

How can I make variable axis with variable ticks? Each time taking the min and max to determine the lowest and highest ticks.

Thank you for thinking with me/helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach to make this slightly more dynamic could be to calculate a `yrange` based on your data's min and max and then derive the `yticks` based on that. So for example

```py
from math import floor, ceil
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(100,)*1.5 - 0.4 # generate some toy data

add_percent = 10
round_to_decimal = 1 # n decimal places, e.g. 2 would mean round to 2nd dec place

ymax, ymin = data.max(), data.min()
offset = (abs(ymin)+abs(ymax))/2 * add_percent/100
yrange = (floor((ymin - offset)*10**round_to_decimal)/10**round_to_decimal, 
          ceil((ymax + offset)*10**round_to_decimal)/10**round_to_decimal)

STEP = 0.1 # step=.1 is a bit arbitrary, depends on your data
yticks = np.arange(yrange[0], yrange[1]+STEP, step=STEP) 
# same as: np.linspace(*yrange, num=np.ptp(yrange)/STEP+1)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(data)
ax1.set_ylim(yrange)
ax1.set_yticks(yticks)
```

Note that I added a rounding of the decimal places and the addition of a relative amount of the `yrange` so that it looks nicer. The result look similar to this:
[image]

Comment: @lanneke113: Great! Basically, it's just about getting the range right, no matter if you use `np.arange` or `np.linspace`. The rest is more like cosmetics, but sometimes it **is** about the looks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That is because `np.arange` is an half open interval. So it doesn't include `ymax` as you desire. If you want a closed interval you can may be try

```
np.linspace(start = ymin, stop = ymax, num = (ymax - ymin)/0.1)
```

Comment: After trying, lower and upper ticks stop while the data is lower/higher (so missing both)

Comment: may be because of `round`. try `floor` and `ceil`

Comment: Trying but it rounds up without decimals. So now the ticks are there but too many haha Because the tick ranges now go from -1 till +1

Comment: Thank you for the floor and ceil tip!